# Truncated normal hurdle (for corner solution responses): how to use results for prediction?

Tags: r, regression, prediction, probit

I have fitted a (Cragg's) truncated normal hurdle model over a dataset in which the dependent variable is either zero or positive. The model consists of two parts: a probit which estimates the probability of the value being zero and a truncated regression which is estimated over the subsample of positive values of the dependent variable.

The output of the estimation (using package `mhurdle` in R) consists of two columns: one gives the probability of y being 0 and the other gives the estimated value for an uncensored observation (let's call this y*).

Now I would like to use these results for prediction, but instead of probabilities and estimated values of the uncensored y I would like to have the estimated values of the dependent variable, including some zeros (or almost zeros). Should I multiply the probability of y NOT being zero by the value of y*? Or should I take all observations for which P(y=0) > 0.5 to be zero and all the others to be equal to y*?

Sorry if the question is trivial but I'm fairly new to statistics and I have not been able to find the answer so far.